# RowNumber Case Statement shows Invalid column

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

**Issue**: I have a query in T-SQL which I have `ROW_NUMBER` as RowNumber set and Partitioned on a column called `UnitNumber` in my SELECT. I want to create a `CASE` statement that says:

`CASE
WHEN RowNumber = 1 then un.SqFt Else ''
End as GrpSqft`

However, I am receiving an error that my RowNumber column is invalid. Am I placing this in the wrong location? I am a rookie to Sql and am having trouble understanding how to define the column as a "built-in" column. I get:

[ Invalid column name 'RowNumber'. ]

**Desired Result** is to have a column "GrpSqft" with all SqFt values that fall into RowNumber=1

Thank you,

Comment: You need to use a subquery or CTE.  You cannot reference a column alias in a `WHERE` clause at the same level of the `SELECT` where it is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs to be

```
CASE     
  WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UnitNumber ORDER BY BLAH DESC) = 1 THEN un.sqft ELSE '' 
END AS GrpSqft
```

Comment: This is working, but it is now giving me an error when converting Varchar into Decimal. I think it is mistaking the unitnumber (varchar) to be converted into decimal (sqft).

Comment: @Geo  Probably have to cast `un.sqft` as string or change the `ELSE ''` to a number like `0.0` or `NULL`